# how to put lsd test letters horizontally in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to put the letters of the mean comparison test horizontally, because there are many and it is not clear in the bar chart, someone could help me.

[image]

Thank you so much

code to get my letters to lie horizontally

Answer (score 0):

you may try to use the `geom_text` to get the expected result

```r
# Load the necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)

# Create a sample dataframe
data <- data.frame(
  Subject = c("CS1", "CS2", "CS3", "CS4", "CS5"),
  labels = c('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI', 'IJK', 'LMN'),
  Score = c(85, 78, 92, 88, 72),
  Lower_CI = c(81, 75, 89, 85, 68),
  Upper_CI = c(89, 81, 95, 91, 76)
)

bar_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Subject, y = Score)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "skyblue", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Lower_CI, ymax = Upper_CI), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = labels), vjust = -3.0) +
  labs(title = "Scores") +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("Score") +
  theme_minimal()

bar_plot
```

[image]